# Is it okay to use symbolic links in my web server?

Tags: apache2, symbolic-link

I have the following directory setup:

```
/var/www/html
```

and

```
/home/tim/Website/files_here
```

The folder `html` is actually a link to `/home/tim/Website`. This means all my Website files are in my home area (they get included in the backup etc).

Is there anything wrong with this method? Is there a better way to get the homepage to be in `/home/tim/Website`?

Are symbolic links on a web server ever incompatible with users not on linux?

Comment: Symlinks are somewhat bad practice on a web-server. There is a good explanation on [sf] about this: http://serverfault.com/a/244612/66406. **But**, in your case, you are using the symbolic link on your root directory, so you can still have the `FollowSymLinks` option in apache disabled and it would still work. So that security problem wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with that, as long as the apache process can read the files in your home directory.

If you're on a development machine, you could just as well put your files under the `/var/www` directory or a subdirectory thereof, but you can also edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` so that the line with `DocumentRoot` points to your `/home/tim/Website/files_here` folder.

There's also [mod_userdir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html), an apache module that permits files in /home/<username>/public_html to be served.